# Query returns empty results using SQLitePlugin

Tags: javascript, ios, sqlite, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am working on an iOS app that was originally written for PhoneGap 1.0.0 that was recently upgraded to 2.2.0 so I can use [SQLitePlugin](https://github.com/chbrody/Cordova-SQLitePlugin) with [SQLCipher](http://sqlcipher.net/). I'm having problems with a `SELECT` statement never returning results, even though I know there's data in there.

Here's the rundown:

1. The database is created with the following code:

```js
    THDatabase.DatabaseConnection = sqlitePlugin.openDatabase(THDatabase.name, THDatabase.currentVersion, THDatabase.displayName, THDatabase.size);

    THDatabase.DatabaseConnection.transaction(THDatabase.CreateUsersTable, THDatabase.FatalErrorCallback);
    THDatabase.DatabaseConnection.transaction(THDatabase.CreateCentersTable, THDatabase.FatalErrorCallback);
    ...
```

1. Once a user registers, the Centers and Users tables have data inserted.
2. When the login screen loads, the db is queried for Centers and Users.

```js
    /* Centers */
    LoadCenters: function LoadCenters() {
        console.log("LoadCenters");
       THDatabase.DatabaseConnection.transaction(THDatabase.LoadCentersImpl, THDatabase.FatalErrorCallback);
        console.log('THDB.LoadCenters called from: ' + arguments.callee.caller.name);
    },

    LoadCentersImpl: function(tx) {
        console.log("Loading centers.");
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Centers', [], THDatabase.LoadCentersParse, THDatabase.RecoverableErrorCallback);
    },

    LoadCentersParse: function(tx, results) {
        console.log('parsing centers');
        var dataArray = [];
        var len = results.rows.length;
        ...
    },

    /* Users */
    LoadUsers: function LoadUsers() {
        console.info("THDB.LoadUsers");
    THDatabase.DatabaseConnection.transaction(THDatabase.LoadUsersImpl, THDatabase.FatalErrorCallback);
    },

    LoadUsersImpl: function (tx) {
        console.info("Loading users...");
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Users', [], THDatabase.LoadUsersParse, THDatabase.RecoverableErrorCallback);
    },

    LoadUsersParse: function (tx, results) {
        console.info('parsing users...');
        var dataArray = [];
        var len = results.rows.length;
        console.log(len);
        ...
    }
    ...
```

The problem I'm having is that after `LoadUsersImpl()` runs, `LoadUsersParse()` never gets the results of the `SELECT` statement. The console.log stops at "Loading users...". I'm still able to log into the app, but nothing else that requires reading from the db works.

I've tried wrapping the call to `LoadUsersParse()` in an anonymous function, passing `tx, results`, which doesn't work. If I pass *just* `results`, then the results of the call show up in the console log, but it stops right after 'parsing users...' shows up.

This same code works fine without the SQLitePlugin installed in PhoneGap, but I can't figure out where it may be causing the problem.

Turning DEBUG on logs this right after "Loading users...":

```
SQLitePlugin.backgroundExecuteSqlBatch: {"executes":[{"query":["BEGIN"],"path":"ThinkHealthDBs.db","callback":"cb55"},{"query":["SELECT * FROM Users"],"path":"ThinkHealthDBs.db","callback":"cb56"}]}
```

This is a problem with and without SQLCipher being used, and on PhoneGap/Cordova 2.1.0.